# How to make sliding button sidebar in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm fairly new to Flex. I want to make a button (icon) on the far right in the middle of the page that display a sliding side bar with multiple buttons in it when you hover over it. I want when the user hover out of the button bar it slides back again.

Conceptually I got the basics of that to work. The issue I'm having is that when the user moves the mouse between the buttons in the sidebar it kicks in changing state and side bar slides back again. I tried using different types of containers and I got the same results.

Any Advice?

Thanks,

Tam
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:VGroup
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
    xmlns:vld ="com.lal.validators.*"
    xmlns:effect="com.lal.effects.*" 
    width="150"
    horizontalAlign="right"
    gap="0">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.lal.model.LalModelLocator;
            var _model:LalModelLocator = LalModelLocator.getInstance();

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:ArrayCollection id="someData"> 
        </mx:ArrayCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="expanded" />
    </s:states>
    <fx:Style source="/styles.css"/>
    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="normal" toState="expanded"  >
            <s:Sequence>
                <s:Wipe direction="left" duration="250" target="{buttonsGroup}"  />
            </s:Sequence>

        </s:Transition>
        <s:Transition fromState="expanded" toState="normal"  >
            <s:Sequence>            
                <s:Wipe direction="right" duration="250" target="{buttonsGroup}"  />
            </s:Sequence>   
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>
    <s:Button skinClass="com.lal.skins.CalendarButtonSkin" id="calendarIconButton" 
              includeIn="normal"
              verticalCenter="0"
              mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>

    <s:Panel includeIn="expanded" id="buttonsGroup"           
              mouseOut="currentState = 'normal' "
              width="150" height="490" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" paddingRight="0" />
        </s:layout>
        <s:Button id="mondayButton" width="120" height="70" mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>
        <s:Button id="tuesdayButton" width="120" height="70" mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>
        <s:Button id="wednesdayButton" width="120" height="70" mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>
        <s:Button id="thursdayButton" width="120" height="70" mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>
        <s:Button id="fridayButton" width="120" height="70" mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>
        <s:Button id="saturdayButton" width="120" height="70" mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>
        <s:Button id="sundayButton" width="120" height="70" mouseOver="currentState = 'expanded'"/>
    </s:Panel>

</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to create a kind of animated pop-up menu behaviour. You want to show the panel when the user hovers over the original button, and hide it again when the user moves their mouse away from the menu.

Your problem is that you are immediately hiding the panel on mouseOut. This is not what you want because you will frequently get the mouseOut event when the user moves the cursor between components within the panel.

A better approach is to have the mouseOut event initiate a timer which will start the transition after a brief delay, and then cancel this timer if you receive another mouseOver event in the meantime.

It would look something like this (untested):

```
mouseOver="showMenu()"
mouseOut="hideAfterDelay()"

protected var t:Timer;

protected function hideAfterDelay ():void {
    killTimer();
    t = new Timer(500, 1);
    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
    t.start();
}

protected function onTimerComplete ():void {
    currentState = "normal";
    killTimer();
}

protected function killTimer ():void {
    if (t) {
        t.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
        t.stop();
        t = null;
    }
}

protected function showMenu ():void {
    killTimer();
    currentState = "expanded";
}
```

You need the mouse handlers on both the original button and the menu. You might need to make some adjustments, but hopefully this shows the basic idea.